# How to stack and align images inside a table cell?

Tags: css, image, alignment, css-tables

I want to place a js analog clock inside a table cell

```
#table02{
    width:100%;
}
#tdLogo02{
    background:#ff0000;
    width:17%;
}
#tdClock{
    text-align:center;  
}
.hands{
    border:thin solid red;
}
#hour {
    z-index: 1;
}
#min {
    z-index: 2;
}
#sec {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

hands should be stacked vertically and aligned both horizontally and vertically inside a cell.
I tried with `position:fixed`, `position:absolute` - hands are stacked but not centered horizontally.

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fptAe/)

Comment: Update http://jsfiddle.net/fptAe/1/

Comment: @PiLHA, yes, but hands should be stacked vertically. `sec` should overlap `min` and `min` should overlap `hour` - according to given z-index

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fptAe/2/ ???

Comment: @PiLHA, no, hands should be stacked so they have the same center point. Like clock hands in a real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to see how the alignment would work out since we can't see the relative images in your fiddle.

This might be a little closer to what you're looking for using PiLHA's fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fptAe/3/

With the containing `#tdClock` center aligned you can set the elements inside to `position: absolute` or `position: relative` allowing you to stack them with the proper z-index.

Assuming the clock images are the same size, all have the same center, and the hands rotate around the same axis, you could define the dimensions of `#tdClock` specifically to the dimensions of the clock images and things should line up.

If the images are different sizes you'll have have to nudge them into place using `left` and `right` positioning, or `margin`.

Comment: Nimoi, hands are all the same size. On my fiddle, if `alt` texts are aligned i.e. centered, the images are aligned too. That's the reason I give them the red border.